# Angular 5 Material 2: Datepickerstyle

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material

I have started to use [Material 2](https://material.angular.io/) in a new Angular 5 project.
I noticed that the style of the Datepicker-toogle seems to have changed.

[image: Old Datepicker]

The old one works fine for me. It opens under the Icon

[image: New Datepicker]

The new one starts on the bottom of the whole page and takes the whole width.

Does anyone know if this is a material related problem? I tested it with Chrome and the new Firefox Quantum. It has the same Result.
Is there a possibility to get the old Datepicker back?

Comment: Please check : its working https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview , must be issue with your css

Comment: I am not using any Css on the Datepicker. I emptied the css of the component and the main css. There is no css rule influencing the datepicker

Comment: Okay then create plunkr / jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with Datepicker :

Here is the link to [**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-datepicker) (Used latest Material package)

Please check your css, must be conflicting with datepickers style.

Comment: Thanks, it was my stupid mistake ;) Misspelled letter in the css for the Theme import

Comment: @FunkRehkitz, Happens sometimes :) , Glad you figured it out.