# Angular 13 Material Datepicker does not apply styles properly

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular13

I've been trying to learn how to use angular 13 datepicker and I can't understand what is not working properly.

Here is my main module.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
  AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the code that I used, based on this [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/angular-material-8-datepicker-tutorial/) :

```
<input [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

And this is how it looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsnsj.png)

And I don't really understand what I am missing and why it doesn't look like it is supposed to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the theme you want to use within your material components.

For example you can use

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

for your global css.

Had the the problem once, too. --> [Angular 5 Material 2: Datepickerstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304580/angular-5-material-2-datepickerstyle)

More infos about the Prebuild themes --> https://v6.material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if angular material is installed correctly with all the css stuff? Check your styles.css if the angular material stuff was added.
Do you have @angular/core in your package.json file?

Another thing you can check is if your datepicker is wrapped by a mat-form-field. It should look like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hello, I checked everything and all seemed to look ok. I have restarted my project a few times and everything started to work, finally!!!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Cool :) I'm very happy that it's working for you now.

Comment: @AlinaC, so you just restart the project, and everything works properly?